# My PC with Windows 10 does not detect 2nd monitor without reconnecting but my Mac does

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a nice Belkin USB hub with a bunch of devices connected, including an external screen. It connects to my laptop with Thunderbolt (USB Type C).

I have two laptops, both are very new, one is a Surface with Windows 10 and the other is a Macbook Pro M1.

Whenever I wake my Mac after a while, it sends a signal to the 2nd screen which opens up too.

However, if it is my PC that is connected, it doesn't send a signal to the 2nd screen no matter what I have tried on it. However, restarting the USB Hub or physically unplugging and reconnecting the USB-C does the trick. I don't want to keep doing that, because I will probably damage the port or the cable or something else by unplugging and reconnecting many times per day.

What can I do on my Windows PC to force it to send a signal?

I have already tried changing screen settings, like duplicate, extend and switching back and forth from different options.